# Why are these states equivalent on this translation table

Tags: automata, finite-automata

Full disclosure: I am trying to understand an answer from the Stanford Automata MOOC.

Why are states F and G equivalent here, such that they would get merged in a minimization process? They both differ on their transitions on 0, so I thought they were distinguishable?

```
    0   1
->A E   D
*B  A   C
C   G   B
D   E   A
*E  H   C
F   C   B
G   F   E
H   B   H
```

Answer (score 3):

```
The two states F and G on similar inputs leads to a final state.
     w(F)+0*1 = w(final-state); 
     w(G)+0*1 = w(final-state);
Here, w(X) is the string that leads to the state X, and 
      + is concatenation operator.
```

Due to the above proposition, it is clear that the two states behave in the same manner and the system's functionality will be unaffected because of merging of these states.

Answer (score 0):

When you say equivalent you need to keep in mind to look if there is no word in length k that separates them.

Moreover you you can see that for a word in length 1 :

$If w_1 = 1 $ then F and G 
enter accepting states B and E

$If w_1 = 0$ then F and G enters a non accepting state C And F

There for they are equivalent for word in length $k=1$

For minimization check this reference: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/automata_theory/dfa_minimization.htm